# Trouble running python file as a keyword in Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am trying to run a python file as a keyword in robot framework. However, when I run it, it says the keyword is not found. I have tried multiple variations on the following code with no luck. Both the robot framework and python file are in the same directory. My goal is to determine if a particular string is in the .csv file

Robot Framework file:

```
*** Settings ***
Library             CheckDataInCSV

*** Test Cases ***
    ${encryption_in_csv}=   CheckDataInCSV.IsDataInCsv  | readings.csv  | C:\\Users\\me\\Downloads
    log   |  ${encryption_in_csv}
```

Python File CheckDataInCSV.py:

```
from robot.api.deco import keyword

@keyword("IsDataInCsv")
def IsDataInCsv(text, downloads_path):
    f = open(downloads_path+'readings.csv', 'r')
    file_contents = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    for item in file_contents:
        if text in item:
            return True
        else:
            pass
    return False
```

I have also tried this without the `@keyword` header as well as just calling the keyword without the library: `IsDataInCsv` instead of `CheckDataInCSV.IsDataInCsv` as well as using a different name for the @keyword and function name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure your `.robot` file syntax is correct. You lost `Test Case name` in your code example.

```
*** Settings ***
Library             CheckDataInCSV

*** Test Cases ***
Test Name What You Want
    ${encryption_in_csv}=   CheckDataInCSV.IsDataInCsv  | readings.csv  | C:\\Users\\me\\Downloads
    log   |  ${encryption_in_csv}
```

Back to your question. According to your code, just add the directory path where `CheckDataInCSV.py` locate to your `PYTHONPATH`. Then it works.

Linux command

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/YOUR_PY_FILE_PATH
```

About keyword `Library` in `*** Setting ***`. There are two ways to import custom libraries.

The first way is like your code. It will search your python file in your `PYTHONPATH`.

```
*** Settings ***
    Library             CheckDataInCSV
```

The other way is like below library name with `.py`. It will search the relative position with the `.robot` file. And also you can use absolute position.

```
*** Settings ***
    Library             CheckDataInCSV.py
```

Comment: Thank you. While I did forget the test case name in my example I have it in my code, but your suggestion for the path led me check on that. It looks like I forgot to add \\ at the end of my downloads path so it was looking for DownloadsCheckDataInCSV.py